# AWS Stepfunction: Define (Prefix)-Name when it's called from another Stepfunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

i have a StepFunction, which triggers another StepFunction.
Works fine.

But, I would like to customize the Name of the Inner-Execution.
E.G. i have the following State in my outer StepFunction

```
"Trigger Inner StepFunction": {
  "Type": "Task",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::states:startExecution.sync",
  "Parameters": {
    "StateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:xxxxx:stateMachine:InnerStepFunc",
    "Name": "$.Name",
    "Input": {
      "StatePayload": "Hello from Step Functions!",
      "AWS_STEP_FUNCTIONS_STARTED_BY_EXECUTION_ID.$": "$$.Execution.Id"
    }
  },
  "Next": "NextStep"
}
```

Then i get the following error:
"Invalid Name: '$.Name' (Service: AWSStepFunctions; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidName; Request ID: 6834b793-667b-4c58-ae19-a1b311a82ee9; Proxy: null)"

If i remove the "name" property below the StateMachineArn Property, then it works, and the inner stepfunction is triggered with a ramdom id as execution name.

But how can i manipulate the name dynamically? Either i would like define it via the Input of the outer step function or define a prefix followed by an random id.

Does anyone have a tip for me?

P.S. I already thought about using a lambda function which is called by the outer StepFunction, and triggers the InnerStepFunction.
But for me it's important that the outer StepFunction waits for complete, before it finished.
And the Inner-StepFunction takes longer then 15 min. (Therefore an sync-call from an Lambda is not an option)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set it by using this syntax below. Keep in mind that your step function will fail if the name that you are passing already exist in the step function.

**"Name.$": "$.Name"**

Comment: Thanks, that's it!